# C++ Visual Studio: linking using pragma comment

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I came across a piece of code which uses #pragma comment(lib, "libraryname").

Why this type of usage as opposed to just linking the library from the properties menu? In what situations is this usage called for? I am in windows using C++ [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010).

It would be nice to see an example which calls for this type of usage.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The library writer can place a `#pragma comment(lib, ...)` command in the public header (.h) file. In this case, the client doesn't need to add this library to the linker dependencies list. By including an h-file in the program, the client is automatically linked to the required library.

Comment: do i need to also physically add the library to the visusal sutudio project in this case ?

Comment: No. but the library must be in the available library search path

Answer (score 24):

Classic example - linking against different versions of the library:

```
#if CURRENT_VERSION >= 10
     #pragma comment(lib, "thirdPartyLibV2.0.lib")
#else //version < 10
     #pragma comment(lib, "thirdPartyLibV1.0.lib")
#endif
```

Answer (score 6):

It's contained in the sense that all it takes is including the header file for the associated library to be automatically pulled in. You can even do `#ifdef..#endif` magic to conditionally bring in the right library based on your environment.

Not everyone is going to be using your MSVC project when starting a new project from scratch, simply being able to `#include` and have it work is the sign of a well written library.