# Building a Python-C-Extension on Windows with a debug Python installation

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, cpython, python-c-api

If I build CPython from source on Windows I encounter problems when I want to pip install a package that contains a C-Extension. It seems like the error happens while linking the libraries.

For example when installing cython (but it also crashes with the same error on other C extension packages):

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python38.lib'
>
> error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe' failed with exit status 1104

The reason why it cannot open the "python38.lib" is because the ".lib" file in debug mode is called "python38_d.lib".

A minimal reproducible example would be (on the command-line) based on the [Quick Reference of the CPython developer guide](https://devguide.python.org/#quick-reference):

```
git clone --branch v3.8.0 https://github.com/python/cpython.git
cd cpython
git checkout v3.8.0
.\PCbuild\build.bat -e -d
.\PCbuild\win32\python_d.exe -m ensurepip
.\PCbuild\win32\python_d.exe -m pip install pip --upgrade -vv
.\PCbuild\win32\python_d.exe -m pip install setuptools --upgrade -vv
.\PCbuild\win32\python_d.exe -m pip install cython -vv
```

The resulting `distutils.sysconfig.get_config_vars()` is:

```
{'BINDIR': '...\\cpython\\PCbuild\\win32',
 'BINLIBDEST': ...\\cpython\\Lib',
 'EXE': '.exe',
 'EXT_SUFFIX': '_d.cp38-win32.pyd',
 'INCLUDEPY': '...\\cpython\\include;...\\cpython\\PC',
 'LIBDEST': '...\\cpython\\Lib',
 'SO': '_d.cp38-win32.pyd',
 'VERSION': '38',
 'exec_prefix': '...\\cpython',
 'prefix': '...\\cpython',
 'srcdir': '...\\cpython'}
```

Is there something I'm missing? Is building C-Extensions on Python-debug builds on Windows simply not supported? If it is supported: how would I do it?

Comment: Distutils gets the information from config. Not sure how it looks like for your setup. Here is an example how one could overrule settings in a setup file https://stackoverflow.com/a/57057959/5769463

Comment: @ead Do you mean the CPython configs or the config from the extension module I'm trying to install? Also shouldn't the CPython build options be picked up by default (and one of the modules I wanted to install contained basically no customizations in the setup) - then why doesn't it realize it has to link against `python38_d.lib`? I tested the commands from the question on my computer and on CI and all of them fail. If you have a workaround or suggestion how to fix this I would appreciate it :)

Comment: I mean distutils.config. You can inspect the provided values and see what is wrong. Sadly for next days I won’t be able to look into this problem

Comment: @ead Thanks for the clarification. I included the values in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linking against `pythonXY.lib` is a little bit sneaky on Windows. When you look at the command line for linking, you will see that no python-library is passed to the linker, i.e. 'link.exe`. Note: This is also the case for Linux, but on Linux one doesn't have to because the needed symbols will be provided by the python-executable.

However, it is easy [to check via](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28304716/5769463) `dumpbin /dependents resulting.pyd`, that there is a dependency on `pythonXY.dll`, also adding `extra_link_args = ["/VERBOSE:LIB"]` to extension-definition and triggering verbose-mode of the linker will show that the linker uses `pythonXY.lib`.

The sneaky part: Microsoft Compler has a convinience-pragma [`#pragma comment(lib, ...)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12821391/5769463) to automatically trigger linking of a library, which is also used [in Python-headers](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a9ed91e6c2f0f1a9960b1382321918448228a801/PC/pyconfig.h#L272-L283):

```c
#               if defined(_MSC_VER)
                        /* So MSVC users need not specify the .lib
                        file in their Makefile (other compilers are
                        generally taken care of by distutils.) */
#                       if defined(_DEBUG)
#                               pragma comment(lib,"python39_d.lib")
#                       elif defined(Py_LIMITED_API)
#                               pragma comment(lib,"python3.lib")
#                       else
#                               pragma comment(lib,"python39.lib")
#                       endif /* _DEBUG */
#               endif /* _MSC_VER */
```

As you can see, to link against the debug version, one needs to define `_DEBUG`.

`_DEBUG` is automatically defined by `distutils` on Windows, if `build_ext` is called with options `--debug`, e.g.

```
python setup.py build_ext -i --debug
```

That can be [translated to `pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-global-option) as

```
pip install --global-option build --global-option --debug XXXXX
```

which can be interpreted roughly as: trigger `build` command (which also includes `build_ext`-command) with option `--debug` prior to installing.

---

Another subtility when building debug C-extensions, there is [more to it on Windows](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a9ed91e6c2f0f1a9960b1382321918448228a801/PC/pyconfig.h#L320):

```c
#ifdef _DEBUG
#       define Py_DEBUG
#endif
```

Having defined  `Py_DEBUG` macro meant incompartible ABIs [until Python3.8](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/138ccbb02216ca086047c3139857fb44f3dab1f9/Doc/whatsnew/3.8.rst#debug-build-uses-the-same-abi-as-release-build), because it also assumed [`Py_TRACE_REFS`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5c403b203510549a3f89d138d3265c5cc0cc12af/Misc/SpecialBuilds.txt#L41) which leads to different memory layout of `PyObject` and some additional functionality missing in the release-mode.

However, since Python3.8, one probably can get away with it by providing the missing `pythonXY_d.lib`/`pythonYX.lib` as a symlink linking to another version.

Comment: Do you know what parts of your answer could be the reason for the downvote? It worked for my use-case and the rest of the answer made sense to me - so I wonder what problems/downsides there could be.

Comment: @MSeifert I don’t know, but would be thankful if somebody would point out the problem.

Answer (score 6):

This code is a little bit hacky, but works for me on MSVC19, allowing to debug application without building debug python libraries.

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define _DEBUG_WAS_DEFINED
#undef _DEBUG
#endif

#include "Python.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG_WAS_DEFINED
#define _DEBUG
#undef _DEBUG_WAS_DEFINED
#endif
```