# _ctypes.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyFloat_Type in embedded Python loaded with dlopen

Tags: python, ubuntu, ctypes, python-embedding

I am using embedded Python (3.9) in ubuntu 20.04 and trying to import ctypes which produces the error `_ctypes.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyFloat_Type`.

I am compiling a **shared object**, which is loaded dynamically using `dlopen()`.

`CMake` is used to build the shared object. I am stating Python3 dependency like so:
`find_package(Python3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Development Development.Embed)` and link using `target_link_libraries(${target_name} Boost::filesystem Python3::Python)`

If I understand correctly, this tells CMake to link directly with `libpython3.9.so` (I also tried to explicitly state linking to `libpython3.9.so`, but that did not solve the issue).
I do see that `libpython3.9.so` exports `PyFloat_Type` and that `_ctypes.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` does not.

The import is simply done by the `PyRun_SimpleString()` function: `PyRun_SimpleString("import ctypes")`.

I should state that I have seen on the web some solutions, but none of them worked (like exporting `LD_FLAGS="-rdynamic"`, but does also did not help).

I should also point out that importing using the interpreter (python3.9) works well.

Here is the build command generated by CMake:
`/usr/bin/c++ -fPIC -g -Xlinker -export-dynamic -shared -Wl,-soname,mytest.python3.so -o mytest.python3.so CMakeFiles/mytest.python3.dir/[mydir]/[myobjects].o  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.71.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.9.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.9.so`

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: I have resolved the issue by loading my shared object using RTLD_NOW|RTLD_GLOBAL in the dl_open

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a C-extension is imported in CPython on Linux, [`dlopen`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) is used under the hood (and per default with `RTLD_LOCAL`-flag).

A C-extension usually needs functionality from the Python-library (`libpythonX.Y.so`), like for example `PyFloat_Type`. However, on Linux the C-extension isn't linked against the `libpythonX.Y.so` (the situation is different on Windows, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59204487/5769463) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62524995/5769463) for more details) - the missing function-definition/functionality will be provided by the python-executable.

In order to be able to do so, the  executable must be linked with [`-Xlinker -export-dynamic`](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_3.html#IDX28), otherwise loader will not be able to use the symbols from the executable for shared objects loaded with `dlopen`.

Now, if the embedded python is not the executable, but a shared object, which loaded with `dlopen` itself, we need to ensure that its symbols are added to the dynamic table. Building this shared object with `-Xlinker -export-dynamic` doesn't make much sense (it is not an executable after all) but doesn't break anything - the important part, how `dlopen` is used.

In order to make symbols from `text.python.so` visible for shared objects loaded later with `dlopen`,  it should be opened with flag `RTLD_GLOBAL`:

> **RTLD_GLOBAL**
> The symbols defined by this shared object will be made
> available for symbol resolution of subsequently loaded
> shared objects.

i.e.

```
shared_lib = dlopen(path_to_so_file, RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_NOW);
```

**Warning:** `RTLD_LAZY` should **not** be used.

The issue with `RTLD_LAZY` is that C-extensions do not have dependency on the `libpython` (as can be seen with help of `ldd`), so once they are loaded and a symbol (e.g. `PyFloat_Type`) from `libpython` which is not yet resolved must be looked up, dynamic linker doesn't know that it has to look into the `libpython`.

On the other hand with `RTLD_NOW`, all symbols are resolved and are visible when a C-extension is loaded (it is the same situation as in the "usual" case when libpython is linked in during the linkage step with `-Xlinker -export-dynamic`) and thus there is no issue finding e.g. `PyFloat_Type`-symbol.

---

As long as the embedded python is loaded with `dlopen`, the main executable doesn't need to be built/linked with `-Xlinker -export-dynamic`.

However, if the main executable is linked against the embedded-python-shared-object, `-Xlinker -export-dynamic` is necessary, otherwise the python-symbols won't be visible when `dlopen` is used during the import of c-extension.

---

One might ask, why aren't C-extension linked against libpython in the first place?

Due to used `RTLD_LOCAL`, every C-extension would have its own (uninitialized) version of Python-interpreter (as the symbols from the libpython would not be interposed) and crash as soon as used.

To make it work, `dlopen` should be open with `RTLD_GLOBAL`-flag - but this is not a sane default option.

Comment: Doesn't dlopen( ) require either RTLD_LAZY or RTLD_NOW?  Which should be OR'd with RTLD_GLOBAL?

Comment: @Jiminion I have added the explicit call (with RTLD_GLOBAL) and information why RTLD_LAZY must not be used.