# python script converted to C code via Cython is throwing this error upon execution: undefined symbol: PyObject_SelfIter

Tags: python, cython

I converted a Python script to C code via Cython, creating "test.c".  I then compile with:

```
 gcc -static test.c -I/home/me/Python-3.9.12/include/python3.9 -o test.exe  -L/home/me/Python-3.9.12/lib -lpython3.9 -lpthread -lutil -lrt -lm -ldl
```

When I run "test.exe" I get this error:

```
 Original error was: /home/me/NEWER/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyObject_SelfIter
```

What I don't understand is that the symbol PyObject_SelfIter **is** defined in libpython3.9.a which I link in as seen in the compilation line.  Why doesn't this linking take care of the undefined symbol noted above?  How can I get around this error?

2 notes:

1. I am linking statically because I want to run the resulting executable on an Android system
2. as a test, I tried compiling without the -static flag, and the executable still yields the same error

thanks for any tips.

Comment: You need `-Xlinker -export-dynamic` when building: similar (but somehow different question) https://stackoverflow.com/a/67894308/5769463 with more explanation about this flag.

Comment: Thanks ead for that.  When I add -Xlinker -export-dynamic and drop -static, it compiles fine and runs fine.  Apparently, compiling with -static is not a good idea when gibc is being linked in.  I found this online where someone wrote:  "reading the LGPL makes it very clear that applications statically linking glibc must be open-source".  Since I wouldn't want to supply all the source I will steer clear of static linking.  When I do "ldd test.exe" part of it shows: libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 which is glibc.  Now I have to figure out how to run this executable on Android.,,.