# Trying to solve "executable: No such file or directory" when running on Android

Tags: android, dynamic, static

I have an executable:

```
 ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked
```

that runs fine on my machine:

```
Linux debian 4.19.0-21-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.249-2 (2022-06-30) x86_64
```

but fails with

> No such file or directory

when run on:

```
 Linux localhost 5.4.61-android11-2-00094-gd61ede24cbb2-ab706444
```

Question: Do I need to copy over all of the libs that I see when I do:

```
ldd test.exe
```

over to the Android device (emulated) to overcome this error? (I'm thinking yes, since it is dynamically linked.). Thanks for any tips here.

Side note: Sort of between a rock and a hard place here since I have read that the LGPL license mandates that if you statically link glibc in your executable you then have to provide all of your source code if you plan to 'publish' your app.  Thus, opting for dynamic linking.

Comment: Given that [Android isn't completely POSIX compliant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27604455/295004) you may want to explain what you are trying to do and how you intend to deliver your solution (i.e. will be an app in the Google Play Store or be for custom rooted devices or Custom ROM).

Comment: I am thinking an app in the Google  Play Store.

Comment: Yes but what does app do? Are you doing image processing, physics modeling, or signal processing. More for suggestions of alternate existing solutions. Android app developers usually call C/C++ via the [NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides) and Java/JNI bridge. Based on your [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73642420/295004) you seem to be using numpy, and while I haven't tried it, I would look at [bulldozer](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) / [python-for-android](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/)

Comment: This app will be doing a lot of processing/computation and will have components in C, Python.   There may be some Fortran components as well, not sure yet.  So your suggestion for NDK and Java/JNI bridge sounds like a good direction to look at.  I'll have to spin up pretty fast on this...